# Screencasting of a Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight, export, frame-rate, encoder

I have got a silverlight application which basically plays videos among other things, as is portrayed below (Silverlight 3):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <MediaElement AutoPlay="True" Source="World.wmv" />
</Grid>
```

But, when I 'screencast' it, using Microsoft Expression Encoder 3 Screen Capture the output video is jagged, and seems like it is recorded at a very low frame rate, while when I 'screencast' a site (for example) one made by the 'Job Output' of Microsoft Expression Encoder 3, it records and plays back at a normal frame rate. Both of the recordings are done with the same settings with the only difference being the code, and work perfectly when viewed in IE8, so I was wondering if there is a property in Silverlight that you need to set, change, etc. that it the Silverlight application gets 'screen casted' correctly.

Thank you,

**Update**
Else, is there a way in which you can export a silverlight page to a video file, or similar?

Comment: I have tried changing these (below) values in the .aspx page that 'hosts' the silverlight control, but I am still having the same problems.

          <param name="framerate" value="60" />
          <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />

Comment: Are you trying to screen capture the video played in a Silverlight video? What are you trying to screencast, it isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was trying to capture the silverlight application playing the video (e.g. a silverlight application in full screen mode playing video, capturing the entire Silverlight Application). I hope this is more clear.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for the screen casting software and not about Silverlight. At least not about Silverlight development. Maybe try the superuser.com site instead.

Comment: Thank you, for your interest. In the end, it was simply eause my computer wasn't powerful enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there is no problem with Silverlight (or my code), rather it was that may laptop was way to underpowered and using a (more) powerful computer heped.